# Freenom URL forwarding to github hosted repo is returning a 502 Bad gateway error

Tags: github-pages

I've been using a freenom domain to forward users to a page hosted on my Github repo because I wanted the URL to be easy to remember instead of Github's long tough to memorize ones. The domain had been up for more than a month but suddenly stopped working today. When I enter it on chrome the page shows a 502 bad gateway error. What can I do?

Comment: [This page](https://www.allconnect.com/blog/502-bad-gateway-error-explained) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

login in your freenom account and check if you still own the domain or not. There is a chance that you have bought it only for a month or 2 and it got expired. If you still own the domain, check the DNS configuration. There should be 5 records added by you in DNS configuration.

All the names fields should be www

4 of them should be type A and last one should be type CNAME

All of them should have TTL as 3600

The target of first 4 records of type A are:

185.199.108.153

185.199.109.153

185.199.110.153

185.199.111.153

and the target of record of type CNAME should be username.github.io where username is your github username.

If all this is properlyl configured, check the CNAME file in your github repository as someone might have changed it (if you gave the access of your account to anyone). Make sure its of the format [www.domain.tk](http://www.domain.tk)     It should not have http:// or https://

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you know if it's somehow possible to use username.github.io/subpath1 as the target for www.mydomain1.tk , and username.github.io/subpath2 as the target for www.mydomain2.tk ?

Comment: No, I am not aware of any methods to do this. I doubt if it's even possible.